# 3g modem is not recognized as an ethernet device without rebooting

Tags: linux, networking, modem, udev, kernel-module

I have two CentOS5 servers with kernel versions 3.4.52 and Huawei e353 usb 3g modem. When I plug the modem to my server usb_modeswitch runs and I can see the modem as an ethernet device with `ifconfig -a` command on the properly working server. But other server is not working properly. I can't see any ethernet after I plug the modem device.

- All of servers have the same versions of the `usb_modeswitch` rpm.

before runnig `usb_modeswitch`

```
 working properly                     not working properly
 # lsusb | grep 12d1                  # lsusb | grep 12d1
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1f01     Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1f01`
```

after running `usb_modeswitch`

```
 working properly                     not working properly
 # lsusb | grep 12d1                  # lsusb | grep 12d1
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:14db     Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:14db

 # rpm -qa | grep modesw              # rpm -qa | grep modesw
 usb_modeswitch-data-20130610-1.lbr   usb_modeswitch-data-20130610-1.lbr
 usb_modeswitch-1.2.6-2               usb_modeswitch-1.2.6-2`
```

- have compared /etc/udev directories of the two servers with diff but there isn't any difference

There is an interesting thing about the not properly working server. After I reboot the server while the usb 3g modem plugged, the modem works properly and I can see it as an ethernet device with the `ifconfig -a` command. So I thought that if i can reload udev, I would see the modem as an ethernet device so I run the following commands:

```
/sbin/udevcontrol reload_rules
/sbin/start_udev
```

But it did not solve the problem. And also I thought that the two servers may have been builded with different kernel parameters. So I compared the output of `sysctl -a` on each server.

```
 # diff config_workingProperly config_notWorkingProperly -y 

CONFIG_TREE_PREEMPT_RCU=y                    | CONFIG_TREE_RCU=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU=y                         | # CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU is not set
# CONFIG_INLINE_SPIN_UNLOCK_IRQ is not set   | CONFIG_INLINE_SPIN_UNLOCK_IRQ=y
# CONFIG_INLINE_READ_UNLOCK is not set       | CONFIG_INLINE_READ_UNLOCK=y
# CONFIG_INLINE_READ_UNLOCK_IRQ is not set   | CONFIG_INLINE_READ_UNLOCK_IRQ=y
# CONFIG_INLINE_WRITE_UNLOCK is not set      | CONFIG_INLINE_WRITE_UNLOCK=y
# CONFIG_INLINE_WRITE_UNLOCK_IRQ is not set  | CONFIG_INLINE_WRITE_UNLOCK_IRQ=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE is not set             | CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y                             | # CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_FD is not set               | CONFIG_BLK_DEV_FD=m
# CONFIG_IDE_GD is not set                   | CONFIG_IDE_GD=m
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDECD is not set            | CONFIG_IDE_GD_ATA=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR_VENDOR is not set        | CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR_VENDOR=y
CONFIG_JFS_FS=m                              | # CONFIG_JFS_FS is not set
# CONFIG_CUSE is not set                     | CONFIG_CUSE=y
CONFIG_ISO9660_FS=m                          | CONFIG_ISO9660_FS=y
CONFIG_UDF_FS=m                              | CONFIG_UDF_FS=y
CONFIG_FAT_FS=m                              | CONFIG_FAT_FS=y
CONFIG_MSDOS_FS=m                            | CONFIG_MSDOS_FS=y
CONFIG_VFAT_FS=m                             | CONFIG_VFAT_FS=y
CONFIG_SQUASHFS=m                            | CONFIG_SQUASHFS=y
# CONFIG_SQUASHFS_XATTR is not set           | CONFIG_SQUASHFS_XATTR=y
# CONFIG_SQUASHFS_LZO is not set             | CONFIG_SQUASHFS_LZO=y
# CONFIG_SQUASHFS_XZ is not set              | CONFIG_SQUASHFS_XZ=y
CONFIG_CRC_ITU_T=m                           | CONFIG_CRC_ITU_T=y
# CONFIG_RCU_BOOST is not set                <
CONFIG_UNINLINE_SPIN_UNLOCK=y                <
CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT=y                       <
CONFIG_JFS_POSIX_ACL=y                       <
CONFIG_JFS_SECURITY=y                        <
# CONFIG_JFS_DEBUG is not set                <
CONFIG_JFS_STATISTICS=y                      <
CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT=y                       <
CONFIG_RCU_CPU_STALL_VERBOSE=y               <
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_TRACER is not set           <
                                             > CONFIG_OPTPROBES=y
                                             > CONFIG_IDE_ATAPI=y
                                             > # CONFIG_IDE_GD_ATAPI is not set
                                             > CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDECD=m
                                             > CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDECD_VERBOSE_ERRORS=y
                                             > # CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_IDE_DISK is not set
```

So what might be causing the problem? Why can't the other server identify my 3g modem as an ethernet device without rebooting?

Comment: Did you ever get it working?